# Order by more than clause in a case statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, case

I'm working a query that will retrieve various personal information, including first and last names.  I want to change the order that the data is returned by based on a passed parameter, called `@p_Code`.  When `@p_Code` is 4, I want to order by first name, then last name.  If it's not 4, then I want to order by last name, then first name.

I'm working with MS Sql.

Here's the query as it stands:

```
Select Last,
       First,
       Phone,
       Email
From Master.dbo.Cust
Order by
case @p_Code
     when '4' then
         ([First], [Last])
     else
         ([Last], [First])
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
DECLARE @p_Code VARCHAR(10)
SET @p_Code = '4'
Select [Last],
       [First],
       Phone,
       Email
From Master.dbo.Cust
Order by
case WHEN @p_Code = '4' THEN (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [First], [Last]))
 ELSE (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Last],[First] )) END
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a test environment handy, but how about this:

```
Select Last,
       First,
       Phone,
       Email,
       (case @p_Code when '4' then [first] else [last] end) as key1,
       (case @p_Code when '4' then [last] else [first] end) as key2
From Master.dbo.Cust
Order by key1, key2
```